# JavaFX DatePicker Multiple Months

Tags: javafx, javafx-datepicker

I recently visited the OpenJFX documentation and I found the following image in this link: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/DatePicker+User+Experience+Documentation

[image: 1]

How to enable it on the JavaFX `DatePicker`?

Comment: That picture appears in the "NICE TO HAVE Functionality" section, of what appears to be a specification paper, and not a documentation article.  This leads me to believe this was simply never implemented...

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented some Date & Time controls. They might not be yet of as high quality as the JavaFX core ones, but they should do what you are looking for:
[LocalDatePicker](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/scene/control/time/LocalDatePicker.html)

```
localDatePicker.setNextMonths(1);
```

The library is Open Source. Maybe you find it useful:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-time</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If you find some issues or have some enhancement requests, please file them here: https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/issues

Here is the original blog post:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/04/drombler-commons-javafx-controls-for.html